# Altium: Snap to X, Y or Z axis during object movement

Tags: altium

When moving object in the schematic view or the PCB view, sometimes we might want an object to only move in X, Y or Z (PCB view only) direction. It might even be that, we want it to move in diagonal way, in only Y=X or Y=-X direction.

Does altium permit snapping to an axis for motion in this way?